# javascript regex split not cross browser

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I am trying to split a string by three keywords like so:

```
var option=$(this).text().split(/(To:|From:|Line:)/);
```

`$(this).text()` is for testing purposes "From:Circular Quay To:Manly Line:F1 Manly"

All "normal" browsers return an array of 7 elements but IE7 & 8 returns an array of 3 elements.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well what happens in IE7/8?

Comment: it spits out an array of three undefined values...

Comment: What's the text you try to split ? Is it the same for all browsers ?

Comment: do you try `console.log($(this).text());`?

Comment: Yes the text() is in all browsers the same I checked that. The text is e.g. `From:Circular Quay To:Manly Line:F1 Manly`

Comment: I feel like this is probably a stupid typo somewhere else... I'll triple check my code and come back... How embarrassing..

Comment: Dominik, if you happen to want to delete your question, please comment before, for example to confirm it wasn't related to split. If it's interesting (not just a typo), you can also answer your own question, if you do it properly.

Comment: Well it sort of works but the same input generates array(7) on all browsers and array(3) on IE7 & 8 ... So that's not consistent... (though I can work around it)

Comment: can you share the value being tested

Comment: @ArunPJohny just edited the question

Comment: In ID 7/8 it is giving `"["Circular Quay ","Manly ","F1 Manly"]" 
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

regex spliting doesn't work the same in all browsers, as is described by [this article](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split).

> - Internet Explorer excludes almost all empty values from the resulting
>     array (e.g., when two delimiters appear next to each other in the
>     data, or when a delimiter appears at the start or end of the data).
>     This doesn't make any sense to me, since IE does include empty values
>     when using a string as the delimiter.
> - Internet Explorer and Safari do
>     not splice the values of capturing parentheses into the returned array
>     (this functionality can be useful with simple parsers, etc.)
> - Firefox
>     does not splice undefined values into the returned array as the result
>     of non-participating capturing groups.
> - Internet Explorer, Firefox, and
>     Safari have various additional edge-case bugs where they do not follow
>     the split specification (which is actually quite complex).

*(note : those behaviors changed somewhat in recent browsers, don't rely on these descriptions for implementing browser specific algorithms!)*

The good news for you, if the order of delimiters is always the same : What probably really interests you, that is the content strings, will be here in all browsers. So you just have to test each string of the array to see if it's an empty string or a delimiter.

If your string always has the delimiters in the same order, you might want to strip them in all browsers by not capturing them :

```
var s = s.split(/To:|From:|Line:/);
```

If you need the delimiters because their order may change, then you'd better split on `\b` and check all strings.